# Why java.security.NoSuchProviderException No such provider: BC?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, jce

The jar (bcprov-jdk16-145.jar) has been added to the project, `Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())` has been added to the class, and `BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME` does return "BC" but AesFileIo.writeFile() still throws `java.security.NoSuchProviderException No such provider: BC`. Any ideas?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class AesFileIo {

    private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    private static final String PROVIDER = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;
    private static final byte[] AES_KEY_128 = { // Hard coded for now
        78, -90, 42, 70, -5, 20, -114, 103,
        -99, -25, 76, 95, -85, 94, 57, 54};
    private static final byte[] IV = { // Hard coded for now
        -85, -67, -5, 88, 28, 49, 49, 85,
        114, 83, -40, 119, -65, 91, 76, 108};
    private static final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec =
            new SecretKeySpec(AES_KEY_128, "AES");
    private static final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

    public void AesFileIo() {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider
                .BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public void writeFile(String fileName, String theFile) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(theFile.getBytes());
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            os.write(encrypted);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StackTraceElement se = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
            System.err.println(se.getFileName() + " " + se.getLineNumber()
                    + " " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097099/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in-android-n/42337802#42337802

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Im not very familiar with the Android sdk, but it seems that the `android-sdk` comes with the `BouncyCastle` provider already added to the security.

What you will have to do in the PC environment is just add it manually,

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

if you have access to the `policy` file, just add an entry like:

```
security.provider.5=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Notice the `.5` it is equal to a sequential number of the already added providers.

Comment: Does this need to be manually added to the PC environment for all PCs that run this application or can this be accomplished programmatically (bcprov-jdk16-145.jar has already been added to the project)?

Comment: You will need to code the `Security.addProvider` in your code, just to make sure it is loaded, and maybe you will need to add your `jar` to your project :)

Comment: I have added `private static final String PROVIDER = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME` (which resolves to "BC") as a field in the code, and I have added the jar to the project but continue to get `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: BC`. I'll edit my original question by including the entire class.

Comment: Got it. Needed `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);` rather than `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);`. I suppose the `Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());` forces the "BC" and the `Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);` is just not understood in this context.

Comment: Works when BC 1.38 throws a "java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC" in the line 'CertStore certStore = cmssignedData.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");'

Answer (score 21):

You can add security provider by editing java.security with using following code with creating static block:

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

**If you are using maven project**, then you will have to add dependency for **BouncyCastleProvider** as follows in pom.xml file of your project.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

**If you are using normal java project**, then you can add download **bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar** from the link given below and edit your classpath.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbcprovextjdk15on147jar.htm

Answer (score 17):

you can add security provider by editing java.security
by adding 
security.provider.=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

or add a line in your top of your class

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

you can use below line to specify provider while specifying algorithms

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "SunJCE");
```

if you are using  other provider like Bouncy Castle then

```
Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

Answer (score 2):

My experience with this was that when I had this in every execution it was fine using the provider as a string like this

```
Security.addProvider(new BounctCastleProvider());
new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
```

But when I optimized and put the following in the constructor:

```
   if(bounctCastleProvider == null) {
      bounctCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    }

    if(Security.getProvider(bouncyCastleProvider.getName()) == null) {
      Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
    }
```

Then I had to use provider like this or I would get the above error:

```
new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
```

I am using bcpkix-jdk15on version 1.65

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using web servers make sure that the bcprov-jdk16-145.jar has been installed in you servers lib, for weblogic had to put the jar in:

```
<weblogic_jdk_home>\jre\lib\ext
```