# Why am I getting this NoSuchProviderException

Tags: java, maven, rsa, bouncycastle, sha

I am trying to use Bouncy Castle as a security provider in a Maven project. It seems to work fine in certain places in the codebase and works completely fine everywhere for some people. However, if I try something like:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
    }
}
```

then I get a `NoSuchProviderException` exception.

In the pom I have Bouncy Castle as a dependency as

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
          <version>140</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have tried with several different JDKs and all give the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711786/254643) in [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711754/why-java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc) SO question, adding the following line should solve your problem.

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: That fixed the problem but do you have any idea why it might work for some people and not for me even if they don't have that line?