# How to load file privakey file types is pem

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I load private (private.pem) 
my code is:

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(private.pem));
    PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader, new DefaultPasswordFinder("mypass".toCharArray()));
    try {
        KeyPair kp = (KeyPair) r.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IOException("The private key could not be decrypted", ex);
    } finally {
        r.close();
        fileReader.close();
    }
```

error is : 
Caused by:

```
java.io.IOException: problem creating RSA private key: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: BC at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding :

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

---

Edit : You may want to go to [Why java.security.NoSuchProviderException No such provider: BC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711754/why-java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc) which may lead to the same problem.