# java cryptography KeyGenerator

Tags: java, security, cryptography, encryption

my code is

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class apiKeyGenerate {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] input = "input".getBytes();
    byte[] ivBytes = "1234567812345678".getBytes();

    Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
    generator.init(128);
    Key encryptionKey = generator.generateKey();
    System.out.println("key : " + new String(encryptionKey.getEncoded()));
   }
}
```

In above code fire Exception is : -  java.security.NoSuchProviderException:
that is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at apiKeyGenerate.main(apiKeyGenerate.java:17)
```

How can I do that ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

the `BC` would indicate BouncyCastle? Why have you commented out `Security.addProvider( new BouncyCastleProvider() )`? You will need to add that provider in the Java security `policy` file then.

Have a look at the [getInstance JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) - the `NoSuchProviderException` is thrown exactly when the provider hasn't been configured. Have you tried the `getInstance(...)` method without the provider argument?

Cheers,

Comment: Also have a look at this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711754/why-java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

      byte[] input = "input".getBytes();
        byte[] ivBytes = "1234567812345678".getBytes();

        Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        **KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");**
        generator.init(128);
        Key encryptionKey = generator.generateKey();
        System.out.println("key : " + new String(encryptionKey.getEncoded()));
       }

}
```

Instead of

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

this line you can try this

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
```

I think this works fine.