# PayTM checksum giving exception error in Android Activity but working fine in the main method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-security, paytm

I am trying to **integrate Paytm** with my android application.
When i generate **paytm checksum through my activity,** i am getting the below exception.

```
I/System.out: MerchantActivity.java checkSumGenerationOnload-method Starts
I/System.out: ChecksumGeneration.java getCheckSum-method Starts
I/System.out: -----------------------------
    40c19e8b2516d6e057c8027826724fac33d3bf60ac8d697569d422571ae46321fro3
    -----------------------------
W/System.err: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: SunJCE
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:466)
        at com.paytm.pg.crypto.AesEncryption.encrypt(AesEncryption.java:34)
        at com.paytm.pg.merchant.CheckSumServiceHelper.genrateCheckSum(CheckSumServiceHelper.java:53)
        at com.example.merchantapp.ChecksumGeneration.getCheckSum(ChecksumGeneration.java:40)
W/System.err:     at com.example.merchantapp.MerchantActivity.checkSumGenerationOnload(MerchantActivity.java:41)
```

But the same method **is giving proper result** when i run it in **main method**.

Log trace:

```
getCheckSumChecksumGeneration.java getCheckSum-method Starts
checkSum: 3kLAvt33DJwodOF/vAPOqrW4LDN3bPbyEBXX10sjgFdjdp6CIS36H4kFj8lwUBnDHEzpo7J0CZlcmi3RCWZQAzN82zi/pPv7vH86iFf3MKU=
ChecksumGeneration.java getCheckSum-method Ends
```

**Code snippet:**
***Activity Class - Having Problem***

```
public class ChecksumGeneration {

    //Below parameters provided by Paytm

    private static String MID = "MyLife19xxxxxxx";
    private static String MercahntKey = "WtxzWMOnZIj0ddU_";
    private static String INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = "Retail";
    private static String CHANNLE_ID = "WAP";
    private static String WEBSITE = "APPSTAGING";
    private static String CALLBACK_URL =  "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDER45676";

    public static void main(String s[]){
        System.out.print("getCheckSum");
        getCheckSum();
    }

    public static String getCheckSum(){

        String checkSum = null;

        TreeMap<String,String> paramMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        paramMap.put("MID" , MID);
        paramMap.put("ORDER_ID" , "ORDER45676");
        paramMap.put("CUST_ID" , "CUST02513");
        paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" , INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID);
        paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID" , CHANNLE_ID);
        paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT" , "1.00");
        paramMap.put("WEBSITE" , WEBSITE);
        paramMap.put("EMAIL" , "thiruppathi.me@gmail.com");
        paramMap.put("MOBILE_NO" , "99425xxxxx");
        paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL" , CALLBACK_URL);

        try{
        System.out.println("ChecksumGeneration.java getCheckSum-method Starts");
        checkSum =  CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum(MercahntKey, paramMap);
        System.out.println("checkSum: "+ checkSum);

        paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH" , checkSum);

        System.out.println("ChecksumGeneration.java getCheckSum-method Ends");

        }catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return checkSum;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code as well

Comment: I didn't see thta,where is it?

Comment: Just added code snippet along with my question.

Comment: what about ChecksumGeneration.getCheckSum()?Could you post it too?

Comment: Sorry, done. :)

Comment: Your emulator's JDK might not have `SunJCE` provider. Did you try running it in a real device?

Comment: What is Cipher.getInstance looks like in your code,I found some similar issue in SO,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711754/why-java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc

Comment: @Kartik : Thanks. I tried adding Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());        But i was getting NosuchAlogorithmException

Comment: "Your emulator's JDK might not have SunJCE provider. "
This makes sense. I will try my real device. I was thinking issue with my jdk/jre/android studio. I will try and let you know.

Comment: When i tried in my real device, my app is closing abruptly, Though i am handling exception as well

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Hi, Was the issue solved ? Could You please post the Solution?